# Compare two vectors and creating a new vector from their comparison

Tags: r

I want to compare two vectors in such a manner that i want to extract lower of each element.Like in following example

```
ab<-c(4,3,5)
cd<-c(2,4,3)
## resulting vector will be
ef<-c(2,3,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is `pmin` which does the elementwise comparision to return the `min`imum value for each element from both the equal length `vector`s

```
ef <- pmin(ab, cd)
ef
#[1] 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

We could try placing your vectors into a data frame and then taking the minimum of each row:

```
ab <- c(4,3,5)
cd <- c(2,4,3)
df <- data.frame(ab, cd)
apply(df, 1, FUN=min)

[1] 2 3 3
```

Comment: Using apply  be inefficient.

Comment: For a pure base R solution, this answer is reasonable.

Comment: I suppose, but are you under the mistaken impression that pmid is not in the base set of packages?